# Global Client/Server C#

Tags: c#, tcpclient

How to make global access to server?
In code ,server its our local ip. On router, i create Wan Virtual server, but i cant send msg from global network. 
I need to send msg from global client. And how i can save clients ip?
Thank in advance! I hope you understand my speech.

```
//Server
TcpListener Server = null;

try
{
    Int32 port = 9595;
    int MaxProc = Environment.ProcessorCount * 4;
    Console.Write(GetIp()+":"+port.ToString());
    Console.Write("\nCount proc * 4:"+MaxProc.ToString());

    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(MaxProc, MaxProc);
    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(2, 2);



    IPAddress LocalIp = IPAddress.Parse(GetIp());

    int count = 0;
    Server = new TcpListener(LocalIp,port);
    Server.Start();
    int max, countmax;
    while(true)
    {
        Console.Write("\nWaiting for a connection... ");

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessMsg,Server.AcceptTcpClient());
        ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out max, out countmax);

        Console.Write("\n Max:" + max.ToString() + "--Count:" + countmax.ToString());

        count++;
        Console.Write("\nConnection#"+count.ToString());
    }


//Client

Int32 port = 9595;
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you want is to be able to connect to this via your public IP address, from anywhere in the world? For that you would have to perform _Port Forwarding_ in your router.

Comment: You would also have to make the `TcpListener` listen to any IP address. So instead of `LocalIp` make it listen to `IPAddress.Any`.

Comment: Any IP solve my problem. Thanks